# С# не могу найти ошибку в индексации

Tags: c#, массивы, циклы

Само задание звучит так: *"Напишите программу с классом, в котором есть неотрицательное целочисленное поле. Опишите для класса индексатор с целочисленным индексом и set-аксессером. Присваивание значения проиндексированному объекту обрабатывается след. образом.В фактически присваиваемом значении берётся только последняя цифра. Индекс определяет разряд в числовом значении поля, в который записывается цифра. Нулевой разряд соотв. единицам, единичный десяткам и т.д. Например,если объект проиндексирован числом 1 и присваивается значение, заканчивающееся на 5, то это означает, что в числе ,которое которое является значением поля , в разряд десятков(1 разряд) нужно записать цифру 5."*

Вот мой код:

```
class MyClass
    {
        public uint ch = 0;

        public uint this [uint k]
        {
            set
            {
                
                uint a = ch;
                int i = 0;
                double x = Convert.ToDouble(ch);
                // Подсчёт "длины" числа
                while (x >= 1)
                {
                    x = x / 10;
                    i++;
                }
                // Создание массива длинной в число
                uint[] arr = new uint[i];
                // Заполнение массива
                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0 ; j--)
                {
                    arr[j] = a % 10;
                    a = (a - (a % 10)) / 10;
                }
                // Присваивание значения "разряду" числа
                arr[k] = value % 10;
                // Запись изменённого числа в поле
                for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    ch = ch + (uint)Math.Pow(10, Convert.ToDouble(j)) * arr[j - 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass A = new MyClass();
            Console.Write("Введите единицы: ");
            A[0] = Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Введите десятки: ");
            A[1] = Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Введите сотни: ");
            A[2] = Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Введите тысячи: ");
            A[3] = Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Число = " + A.ch);
            Console.Write("Измените десятки: ");
            A[1] = Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Число = " + A.ch);
        }
    }
```

**Вылезает ошибка в строке:**

```
arr[k] = value % 10;
```

**"Индекс находится вне границ массива"**

Не могу понять почему и прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы в какие-то дебри полезли, зачем массив, `double` и 3 цикла?

И лучше называйте переменные и поля понятными именами: `ch` похоже на `character`, лучше `number`.

```cs
class MyClass
{
    public uint number = 0;

    public uint this[uint k]
    {
        set
        {
            uint multiplier = (uint)Math.Pow(10, k); // получить множитель разряда
            uint digit = number / multiplier % 10; // получить цифру
            number -= digit * multiplier; // стереть старую цифру
            number += value % 10 * multiplier; // записать новую
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод

```
Введите единицы: 1
Введите десятки: 2
Введите сотни: 3
Введите тысячи: 4
Число = 4321
Измените десятки: 5
Число = 4351
```

А если бы я любил сокращать как вы, у меня вообще получилось бы вот так :)

```cs
set
{
    uint m = (uint)Math.Pow(10, k);
    n += (value % 10 - n / m % 10) * m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Напиши:

```
try {
    arr[k] = value % 10;
} catch {
    Console.WriteLine($"arr[{k}] = {value % 10} Lenght:{arr.Lenght}");
}
```

И сразу станет очевидно.

Comment: спасибо, ошибку понял,длину массива исправил, теперь программа работает,но работает неправильно,число по итогу не получается, не пойму почему.
Вывод получается таким:
``Введите единицы: 1;
Введите десятки: 2;
Введите сотни: 3;
Введите тысячи: 4;
Число = 4787``